# Make text take up n lines?

Tags: css

Is there a CSS property that will make text try to fit onto 2 lines?

[image]

I could use a non-breaking space character to prevent a single orphaned word, but I thought there was a smarter property for new browsers which makes the text intelligently wrap so that both lines are of a similar length?

Answer (score 0):

There is a rather new CSS property called `text-wrap`. You can set it to `balance`, although the property is only supported in Edge, Chrome and Opera:
https://caniuse.com/css-text-wrap-balance

```css
p {
  max-width: 250px;
}

p.balance {
  text-wrap: balance;
}
```

```html
<p>this is my text and i dont like how it wraps</p>
<p class="balance">this is my text and i dont like how it wraps</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make the whole thing in a div with a specified width and adjust the width until it made the lines equal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).